# Why does traceroute fail?

Tags: networking

Let's say I traceroute to address A: 24.205.224.36

Here's what the start of the traceroute looks like:

```
$ traceroute -d 24.205.224.36
traceroute to 24.205.224.36 (24.205.224.36), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  4.799 ms  12.566 ms  0.766 ms
 2  10.101.58.1 (10.101.58.1)  8.915 ms  7.186 ms  8.070 ms
 3  dtr01thdlor-tge-0-1-0-1.thdl.or.charter.com (96.34.105.152)  8.810 ms  9.118 ms  14.246 ms
 4  acr01thdlor-tge-3-1.thdl.or.charter.com (96.34.104.235)  7.578 ms  7.420 ms  7.702 ms
```

But then I try traceroute to address B: 192.168.1.1 and I get just * * * :

```
 $ traceroute -d 192.168.1.1
 traceroute to 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
```

This is despite the fact that address B is on the way to address A.

How can A be reachable on the way to B, but not reachable directly?

Confusing.

This is the traceroute version I am using:

```
$ traceroute -v
Version 1.4a12+Darwin
Usage: traceroute [-adDeFInrSvx] [-A as_server] [-f first_ttl] [-g gateway] [-i iface]
[-M first_ttl] [-m max_ttl] [-p port] [-P proto] [-q nqueries] [-s src_addr]
[-t tos] [-w waittime] [-z pausemsecs] host [packetlen]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the device that is your default gateway / first hop, I expect. Use `traceroute -I 192.168.1.1` and use ICMP instead of default UDP. Then it will probably work.